# Having trouble initializing jagged array ('Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error)

Tags: c#

As per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays
I have initialized my jagged array as follows:

```
private float[][] bulletBehaviour;

void Start()
{
    float[][] bulletBehaviour = new float[1][]
    {
        new float[4] {12.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 0.5f} // [typeSelected][speed, size, lifeTime, fireRate, damage]
    };
}
```

Then any time I try to use bulletBehaviour elsewhere it gives the error in the title.
Note: There will be more arrays eventually (if I can get them working)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `Start()` method, delete the `float[][]` before assigning a value to the variable, like so:

```
private float[][] bulletBehaviour;

void Start()
{
     /* Before:
    float[][] bulletBehaviour = new float[1][]
    After: */
    bulletBehaviour = new float[1][]
    {
        new float[4] {12.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 0.5f} // [typeSelected][speed, size, lifeTime, fireRate, damage]
    };
}
```

Why?

When you start a line with a variable type, you're telling the compiler "I'm defining a *new* variable of this type."

So you were creating a new local variable called `bulletBehaviour`, and everything that followed assigned a value to this local variable, not the member variable that you defined in the body of the class itself. So the member variable stayed unassigned (null).

If for some reason you need to have a local variable or argument of the same name inside a method, you can still refer to the member variable by qualifying it with `this.` like so:

```
string greeting = "Hello";

public void MyMethod() {
    string greeting = "Yo";

    Debug.Log(greeting);  // Refers to the local variable - outputs "Yo"
    Debug.Log(this.greeting); // Refers to the member variable - outputs "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I've been self-teaching, so the explanation really helps!